# Generate noiseless binary image and skeleton from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I have a overlapping filaments image. I am interested in generating the noiseless binary image and subsequently use it for skeleton generation. I have tried different ways to get skeleton but not able to succeed.  Below find the code written in python for the same and attached skeleton image generated through it. It would be great if anyone help in solving issue.

Original vs Skeleton image:

[image: 1] [image: 2]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology, graph
from skan import Skeleton
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img00 = cv2.imread(r'img_test.jpg')
img01 = cv2.cvtColor(img00, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('1',img01)

img02 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img01,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,5,5)
cv2.imshow('2',img02)


i_size = min(np.size(img02,1),600) # image size for imshow
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)  # Creating kernel

# Using cv2.erode() method 
img_erosion = cv2.erode(img02, kernel, borderType = cv2.BORDER_REFLECT, iterations=1, borderValue = 1)

filterSize =(5,5)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, filterSize)
tophat_img = cv2.morphologyEx(img_erosion, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, kernel)
img03 = cv2.bitwise_not(tophat_img)
cv2.imshow('3',img03)

kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(2,2))
img04 = cv2.morphologyEx(img03, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel1)
img04 = cv2.morphologyEx(img04, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel1)
cv2.imshow('4',img04)

thresh = (img04/255).astype(np.uint8)

# skeleton based on default method
skeleton1 = skeletonize(thresh)
skeleton2 = (skeleton1*255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('5',skeleton2)

# Avg diameter calculation
diameter = np.sum(thresh)/np.sum(skeleton1)
print('diameter',diameter)

cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: use AI for the segmentation. semantic segmentation should make easy work of this, given some training data.

Answer (score 0):

Straight binarization followed by morphological closing can give interesting results, though they are sensitive to parameters.

[image]

Comment: Doust:  Thanks. Interesting output in terms of binary image. can you please share code for it ?

Comment: If you want... (mViz code)

Comment: @Daust:  is mViz a code or opensource library? I do not have know it.  can you please provide some additional info how to generate above binary?

Comment: I gave sufficient information !